# Mask for input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to make a mask, type time 11:24, that would work in IE7, IE8, IE9 crome.
I use this library here, but it only works in the chrome https://raw.github.com/fabiomcosta/jquery-meiomask/08b92c411a60ace9131de697179fda433178b8d9/jquery.meio.mask.js.
 Tell the library ready for work in all browsers

Comment: Try this plugin http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about IE9 but in the ajax control toolkit there's maskedtextbox like the one in visual studio toolbox. it works in IE 8, firefox and chrome.

see demo:
http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx

Comment: I did not notice that this is a asp. I need to php.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.meiocodigo.com/projects/meiomask/

i think this works fine on all browsers

Edit:
meioMask compatibility

meioMask has been tested with jQuery 1.7.2 on all major browsers:

```
Firefox2, Firefox3, Firefox3.5 (Win, Mac, Linux);
IE6, IE7, IE8 (Win);
Chrome (Win, Mac, Linux);
Safari3.2, Safari4 (Win, Mac, iPhone, yes, it supports iPhone!);
Opera (Win, Mac, Linux).
```

this note was on their own site